# Bootstrap Validator & Image Picker - How to validate form if any one of two available select inputs are chosen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using [bootstrap-validator](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/) for form validation, and [imagePicker](http://rvera.github.io/image-picker/) to display the selects. It works great, but I have come across an instance that I can't solve on my own. I have a form with two inputs and I need the form to validate if any of the two inputs are selected. I couldn't find an example on the bootstrap-validator or imagePicker options

Ideally I'd like to accomplish this with the bootstrap-validator or imagePicker plugin. If not I'll do an if statement to toggle the required property.

Here is my form, any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

**HTML**

```
<form role="form">

      <h4>Select list #1</h4>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="hide" for="select-list-1">Select list #1</label>
        <select id="select-list-1" multiple="multiple" class="image-picker form-control" required>
          <option>Option 1</option>
          <option>Option 2</option>
          <option>Option 3</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <h4>Select list #2</h4>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="hide" for="select-list-2">Select list #2</label>
        <select id="select-list-2" multiple="multiple" class="image-picker form-control" required>
          <option>Option 1</option>
          <option>Option 2</option>
          <option>Option 3</option>
        </select>
      </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default action-btn">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I decided the best way was not to use bootstrap-validator on this form. I used the clicked callback function in imagePicker to determine if any of the images were selected. I then made the button disabled by default and toggled this depending if any images were selected or not.

```
//Image Picker
$("form select").imagepicker({
    show_label: true,
    clicked: function(){
        if($('form .thumbnails li div').hasClass('selected')){
            // do something
            $("form button").removeClass('disabled');
        } else {
            // do something else
            $("form button:not('.disabled')").addClass('disabled');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Please note this function applies to the code that imagePicker creates on the fly, that's why '.thumbnails li div' is not found in the supplied HTML code.